# Google Places API - radarSearch search by name

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-maps, google-places-api

I'm using [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#radar_search_requests) and using radarSearch to list establishments. However I'm getting a problem when I search using name parameter.

It returns several places, but I'd like to get the exactly name.

In this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/fautepdf/6/), I'd like to have returned "best buy" but it is returning places not related to the word I'm searching for.

```
            var map;
  var infoWindow;
  var service;

  function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.7490, -84.3880),
      zoom: 11,
      styles: [
        {
          stylers: [
            { visibility: 'simplified' }
          ]
        },
        {
          elementType: 'labels',
          stylers: [
            { visibility: 'on' }
          ]
        }
      ]
    });

    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

    performSearch();
  }

  function performSearch() {
    var request = {
      location: new google.maps.LatLng(33.7490, -84.3880),
      radius: 50000,
      name: "Best Buy"
    };
    service.radarSearch(request, callback);
  }

  function callback(results, status) {
    if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      alert(status);
      return;
    }
    for (var i = 0, result; result = results[i]; i++) {
      createMarker(result);
    }
  }

  function createMarker(place) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: place.geometry.location,
      icon: 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/yellow-dot.png'
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      service.getDetails(place, function(result, status) {
        if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          alert(status);
          return;
        }
        infoWindow.setContent(result.name);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    });
  }

  initialize();
```

Comment: `I'd like to have returned "best buy" but it is returning places not related to the word I'm searching for.` => can you add details about the data you think are not related? Is it the fact that the name is not exactly "Best Buy"?
Not clear when looking at your sample

Comment: Hi Nicolas, that's right. I'm getting results where it doesn't match exactly to "best buy".

Like "Buy here pay here" or "We buy land"

Answer (score 0):

According to Google Places Search API (https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search), on the `name` parameter:

> name — One or more terms to be matched against the names of places,
>   **separated by a space character**. Results will be restricted to those
>   containing the passed name values. Note that a place may have
>   additional names associated with it, beyond its listed name. The API
>   will try to match the passed name value against all of these names. As
>   a result, places may be returned in the results whose listed names do
>   not match the search term, but whose associated names do.

I think you should escape your space character by using `\` before it:

```
var request = {
  location: new google.maps.LatLng(33.7490, -84.3880),
  radius: 50000,
  name: "Best\ Buy"
};
```

Note: In your fiddle, I only got "Best Buy..." / "Best Buy" / ".. Best Buy..." result, I don't get your problem

Update fiddle with this change (and small jsfiddle improvements): https://jsfiddle.net/fautepdf/16/

Comment: Hi Nicolas, I'm still getting dirty places. 

[Here it is a example][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/jeKqn.png

Comment: WIth the jsfiddle or directly in your code? I don't have the point you have in the screen capture!
I have the same results if I let only "Buy" in the search field

Comment: Sorry I didn't say this earlier, but I really appreciate your help on this, however using the jsfiddle you provided, I'm still getting this misleading info (as shown in the screenshot). Even using another browser, cleaning cookies...

Comment: I just made a new test.

Using Chrome I'm getting this unwanted results.
Using Firefox I'm getting 90% of data correctly. Could be a problem with cookies?

Comment: Very strange. I'm using Chrome and don't get the unwanted results. Maybe you should try after cleaning your cache/cookies (and/or private navigation)